# spriteKit didBeginContact fails to addChild

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working through some collision detection issues with SpriteKit. I have the correct collisions firing in `didBeginContact` which is great.

Now I'm hitting a scoping issue where I'm not able to remove and add a child within the scene based on one of the collision hits. The first detection does work, but the second one fails.

Here is the `didBeginContact` function that gets called correctly. Both of these methods are in my root SKScene:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {        
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Head && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Food) {            
        //remove and place new food
        //this one works great
        self.placeFoodInRandomGridLocation()
    } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Food && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Body) {
        //remove and place new food
        //this one FAILS
        self.placeFoodInRandomGridLocation()
    }
}

func placeFoodInRandomGridLocation() {
    snakeFood!.removeFromParent()
    let randomX = arc4random_uniform((myGrid.columnCount))
    let randomY = arc4random_uniform((myGrid.rowCount))
    snakeFood = Food(size: CGSize(width: myGrid.snakeWide/2, height: myGrid.snakeHigh/2), gap: gapFactor)
    snakeFood!.position = CGPoint(x: colLines[Int(randomX)], y: rowLines[Int(randomY)])
    //THIS child does not appear for the 2nd collision. It DOES for the first.
    self.addChild(snakeFood!)
}

struct ColliderType {
    static let Head:          UInt32 = 0
    static let Food:          UInt32 = 0b1
    static let Body:          UInt32 = 0b10
}
```

Comment: Note, I've also tried just positioning "snakeFood" instead of removing and adding. That also fails.

Comment: Are you sure that in the `else if` `bodyA` is food, and not a body?  I would recommend testing to see which bit mask is of a lower value, and then comparing it with the lower valued `ColliderType`.

Comment: I should also clarufy that both collisions successfully call the placefoodinrandomgrid location method.

Comment: Could you post the declaration for the bitmask values?

Comment: added bitmask values.

Comment: Looks like you are checking for two cases: when the head hits the food when the head is physics body A and the food is physics body B, and when the body hits the food when the body is physics body B and the food is physics body A.  That doesn't sound like an exhaustive set of circumstances for what you want.  You *probably* want to check irregardless of which physics body is which.  For instance, your code would fail if the head hits the food when the physics bodies are done in reverse order (A is B and B is A).

Comment: The checks were working fine. In testing the gameplay i'm getting exactly what I need in terms of identifying collisions. The issue was that once I was at the placeFoodInRandomLocation method the position of snakeFood wouldn't update. You can see my current solution now with tracking a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to update the position of the snakeFood object directly after the didBeginContact collision fired. I was able to track a boolean in didBeginContact which I could then capture in didSimulatePhysics. This solution works well:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Head && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Food) {
        placeFood = true
    } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Food && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Body) {
        placeFood = true
    } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Body && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Food) {
        placeFood = true
    }

}

func placeFoodInRandomGridLocation() {
    let randomX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myGrid.columnCount))
    let randomY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myGrid.rowCount))
    snakeFood!.position = CGPoint(x: colLines[Int(randomX)], y: rowLines[Int(randomY)])
}

override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    if (placeFood == true) {
        placeFood = false
        placeFoodInRandomGridLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: also note i'm not adding the child anymore. i'm just re-positioning.